# How to store logs generated by curl , using the library CurlRestAssuredConfigFactory

Tags: java, api, curl, rest-assured

I'm using the library CurlRestAssuredConfigFactory , and using the following code

```
   private final Options options = Options.builder().useLogLevel(Level.INFO).build();
   private final RestAssuredConfig config = CurlRestAssuredConfigFactory.createConfig(options);

RequestSpecification spec = getRequestSpecification(RestAssured.given());
    return spec.config(config).when().get(this.url).then().extract().response();
```

After executing last piece of code, curl logs are generated with complete URI and headers, I wish to store those logs and pass them in the report.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://github.com/dzieciou/curl-logger#custom-curl-handling

final List<String> curls = new ArrayList<>();
CurlHandler handler = new CurlHandler() {
  @Override
  public void handle(String curl, Options options) {
    curls.add(curl);
  }
};
List<CurlHandler> handlers = Arrays.asList(handler);
CurlRestAssuredConfigFactory.createConfig(handlers)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Allure for reporting, I'd recommend you to use **allure-rest-assured** library in order to store and review logs directly attached to the appropriate test in report.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-rest-assured/2.13.2

Just add this dependency to your project and then use as a filter in 1 line in the ReqestSpecification:

```
  private static RequestSpecification getReqSpec() {
    return new RequestSpecBuilder()
      .addFilter(new AllureRestAssured())
      .setBaseUri(BASE_URI)
      .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAuthToken())
      .setAccept(ContentType.JSON)
      .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
      .build();
  }
```

Then:

- run your tests
- generate and open Allure report
- take a look an the attachments to desired test

Comment: No, he wants to save cUrl log, not request or response log.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot , but I got the answer from readme of git repo itself 

https://github.com/dzieciou/curl-logger#custom-curl-handling

final List<String> curls = new ArrayList<>();
CurlHandler handler = new CurlHandler() {
  @Override
  public void handle(String curl, Options options) {
    curls.add(curl);
  }
};
List<CurlHandler> handlers = Arrays.asList(handler);
CurlRestAssuredConfigFactory.createConfig(handlers)